# I want to add small input box or text box right side of every card on left lane only in react-trello

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

community.
I am working on one of my projects and I stuck on adding text box or input box right side of every card.

here is the working example of react-trello.

[react-trello](https://codesandbox.io/s/1o3zj95m9j)

Comment: you need to customize react-trello or use your own custom design for that

Comment: from reading the documentation, it looks like that functionality is not built in. You could always fork the [github repo](https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello), and make the card look however you like!

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I already tried but unable to add text box there, can you give me a proper solution